# Not able to click a dropdown field which is designed in the DOJO Html using selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, dojo

I am not able to click an arrow drop down filed in my application using selenium web driver.

I tried lot of XPath using class name and relative XPath

This is the code used for the problem

```
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon pentaho_dijitEditorIconExport"
             data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
```

Comment: Please add some more portion of html. Its too difficult to guess and help with this little html part

Answer (score 0):

Please add some more information from your HTML i just add some text and xpaths are like that

```
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon pentaho_dijitEditorIconExport"
             data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode">test</span>
```

Xpaths are:

```
//span[@class='dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon pentaho_dijitEditorIconExport']
```

or

```
//span[@data-dojo-attach-point='iconNode']
```

or

```
//span[@data-dojo-attach-point='iconNode' and @class='dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon pentaho_dijitEditorIconExport']
```

Add some more informaton if you have any concern

Comment: I tried all Xpaths which are given above,but still its not working

Comment: 'By.xpath: //span[@data-dojo-attach-point='iconNode' and @class='dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon pentaho_dijitEditorIconExport']' not found

Comment: What are the issues

Comment: I am getting this issues:

Comment: 'Object Repository/Pop_Mgr/InteractiveFile/ExcelWorkbook' located by 'By.xpath: //span[@class='dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon pentaho_dijitEditorIconExport']' not found)

Answer (score 0):

dojo combo are basically `<input type= "text">`, once u click on it or type the first letter of the option you want to select, a `<div>` is attached to the html body which has following structure:-

```
<div resultname="option name" resultvalue="option value" class="dojoComboBoxItem dojoComboBoxItemEven ">Option Value</div>
```

now there are 3 steps to select from dojo

1. identify the input text
2. type the first few letters of the option you want to select
3. create dynamic xpath to select the option

the code goes as followes

```
String optionName = "Option You Want to Select";
WebElement dojoBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<provide the xpath here>"));
dojoBox.sendKeys(optionName.substring(0,2));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page-home']/span/div[@resultvalue='" + optionName + "']")).click();
```

if you are not sure about the dynamic xpath structure, then manually select the option, and inspect the div you have added, generally it should have the similar structure.